# Apache Tomcat Shutdown :java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: java, tomcat, shutdown

I installed tomcat 7 on centos 5.8. 
Then I executed ./startup.sh and ./shutdown.sh, it worked well.

Then I put a something.war under the  webapps/. it worked well too.
But when i shutdown the tomcat, it doesn't work and throws an exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:499)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:371)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:453)
```

And i'm sure:

1. The tomcat is running and works well before i execute ./shutdown.sh
2. The process of the tomcat is still alive, but it isn't listening the port 8080, after i execute ./shutdown.sh

Comment: No, i shutdown it, but the process is still alive.

Comment: why do you think it is alive?

Comment: ensure you have sufficient privileges as you are using linux.

Comment: Using  command 'ps', i can see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some possibilities come to my mind:

- It is possible that your webapp starts a thread that doesn't run as "daemon" - thus keeping the process alive. Change this in the webapp to behave more friendly - or implement a listener that shuts down the thread when your webapp is shutting down. You can test this by triggering a thread dump (`kill -3 pid`) on the running tomcat process, the output will (most likely) end up in catalina.out
- There might be another tomcat running, on a different port - that's what you see in `ps` output
- You have changed the "shutdown" port (see tomcat's `server.xml`) - that's what shutdown.sh is contacting in order to instruct tomcat to shut down

Comment: I guess that it because a none-daemon thread, i will check it. thanks!

Comment: checked that there's an ActiveMQ thread not running as daemon. so maybe this is the issue. thanks

Comment: I also noticed some non-daemon thread spawned by tomcat as well, is that going to be a problem when stopping tomcat

Comment: I'd expect tomcat to know how to tear down its own threads. The "daemon" is just required if it's ok to forcefully shut down the threads, e.g. when they don't care if tomcat is going down around them - thus keeping the process alive.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have localhost in /etc/hosts for 127.0.0.1

Mine used to be like this

```
127.0.0.1   centosIGW localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

It works after I add localhost to 127.0.0.1

```
127.0.0.1   centosIGW localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```